# I feel sorry for Tester101

Tags: discussion

The question activity this morning makes it look like @Tester101 has the worst-constructed house in the industrialized world.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, just running through the [review queue](http://diy.stackexchange.com/review).

Comment: Snork. You got an actual LOL out of me this morning :)

Comment: @Tester101, Hey, while I've got you here, can you tell me what size wire for my garage?

Comment: If I had my way, mod edits wouldn't push things to the front page. But alas, I don't write the stored procedures.

Comment: @Tester101 I agree that questions shouldn't always jump to the front because a mod is editing or doing other maintenance. In many cases, though, it's a way to bring attention to old but still relevant questions, many of which have been asked again since. [This](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer) one of yours is a good example. That's just my uninvited two cents worth :)

Comment: I think @Tester101 should suck it up. He needs to do more around here to keep things cleaned up. Actually, I'm just kidding! Keep up the good work! :D

Comment: @Mazura, the answer is 4/0 - 4/0 - 4/0 - 4/0 Copper SER cable.  We can talk about breaker size after you pull the wire.